# Kubernetes: Unable to access to kubernetes dashboard

Tags: azure, kubernetes, continuous-deployment, azure-aks

I add bitnami.bitnami/rabbitmq into my acr.
 
In VSO release pipeline, I add 2 tasks kubectl run & expose, looks like below.

```
kubectl run rabbitmq --image xxxxxx.azurecr.io/bitnami.bitnami/rabbitmq:3.7.7 --port=15672
kubectl expose deployment rabbitmq --type=LoadBalancer --port=15672 --target-port=15672
```

After save and release it, everything is successful, but now I can't proxy into my dashboard using

```
az aks browse -g {groupname} -n {k8sname}
```

When I remove the above 2 task in my release, I able to connect to my dashboard.
Can someone explain to me what going wrong, how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the pods work well in your Azure Kubernetes Cluster. If everything is OK. Then you should make sure that if your current OS has the browser. The command `az aks browse -g {groupname} -n {k8sname}` need a browser to open the dashboard where it executes.

You can open the k8s dashboard in another OS with the command you posted after you get the credential with the command `az aks get-credentials -g {groupname} -n {k8sname}`. Of curse, you need to execute `az login` first.

If things above all are OK, you could try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#i-cant-seem-to-connect-to-the-dashboard-what-should-i-do).

Comment: When executing az aks browse -g {groupname} -n {k8sname} it will launch the browser but not able to load the kubernetes dashboard. Please read again my question

Comment: @Herman Do you get credential from the Azure Kubernetes Cluster? By the way, please be friendly to all the people who want to help you.

Comment: Yes I have perform az login & az aks get-credentials.

Comment: @Herman Do you try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#i-cant-seem-to-connect-to-the-dashboard-what-should-i-do)?

Comment: I read the docs, I can't seem to connect to the dashboard. I try the url is given is not working as well. btw how to check the kube-proxy?

Comment: @Herman You can check with the command `kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system` and there is a pod name like this `kube-proxy-z5stn`. You can check if it is in the running state.

Comment: I check the status is running kube-proxy-lrk96                      1/1       Running   208        50d What is the next step to check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178657/discussion-between-charles-xu-msft-and-herman).